# Check validity of field within a directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'd like to enable / disable a button within a directive based on the validity of a textfield that also lives within the directive without having to know the parent form name (which would make my directive much less reusable).

Here's an example of the problem.

```
.directive('sendEmail', function () {
return {
  scope: {
    email: '='
  },
  require: 'ngModel',
  replace: true,
  template:
    '<input name="email" type="email ng-model="email">' + 
    '<button ng-disabled="myForm.email.$invalid">Send confirmation email</button>',

  link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    // Do something useful in here.
  }

};
```

});

Ideally I'd be able to do something that means I can write this directive without having to know `<form name="myForm">`

I'd greatly appreciate thoughts on how to do this the angular way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ngForm`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angForm) inside of your directive template and reference that form to validate the button.

```
.directive('sendEmail', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            email: '='
        },
        require: 'ngModel',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-form name="myForm"><input name="email" type="email ng-model="email"><button ng-disabled="myForm.email.$invalid">Send confirmation email</button></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically compile the template and render like this. Please take a look at the demo I created.

<kbd>**[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/USrPk/)**</kbd>

```
app.directive('sendEmail', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        replace: true,

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var formName = element.parent().prop('name');
            var template = '<div><input name="email" type="email" ng-model="email">' +
                '<button ng-disabled="' + formName + '.email.$invalid">Send confirmation email</button></div>';

            element.html(template);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    };
});
```